# Replace last digit

Tags: sql

How can I replace the last digit of a given field with `1`?

Example : `code = 133` and I want to replace last digit `3` with `1`.

Comment: Please specify the DB(ORACLE or MSSQL or MYSQL etc)

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE SomeTable
    SET SomeColumn = LEFT(SomeColumn, LEN(SomeColumn)-1) + '1';
```

Answer (score 1):

use left string func and concatenate it with '1'

```
SELECT left('133',2)+'1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(Code,2) + '1'
```

or

```
SELECT LEFT(Code , LEN(Code) -1 ) + '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a numeric field, you can calculate its value divided by 10, floor it, *multiply again by 10*, and just add 1.

```
SELECT 10*FLOOR(code/10)+1
```

Or, possibly faster,

```
SELECT code - (code%10) + 1
```

Comment: `133 / 10 = 13.3.  Floor(13.3) = 13.  13 + 1 = 14.`

Comment: Thank you. I had left out quite an important bit of the recipe :-)